# How to fix the error 'Reference Error: "document" is not defined'

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a dynamic drop down list in Apps Script. I created the function in the manner shown below by referencing from other examples. However, testing the function returned 'Reference Error: "document" is not defined'.

```
function email_dropdown(divname) 
{
    var open_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://spreadsheet.url');
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(open_sheet);
    var active_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Trial Auth (Email List)');
    active_sheet.activate();


    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    var dropdown = "<select id = 'email_dropdown'> Email";

    var row_val = active_sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
    var row_length = row_val.length;
    var row_data = active_sheet.getRange("B2:B");

    for (var row = 2; row <= row_length; row++)
    {
      dropdown = dropdown + row_data.getCell(row, 1).getValue();
    }

    dropdown = dropdown + "</select>"
    Logger.log(dropdown);
    new_div.innerHTML = dropdown;
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(new_div);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Scripts do not have access to the Document Object Model (DOM) since they run on the server. If you wish to show HTML content to your users inside the Google Sheet, use the [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) instead.

Comment: Does that mean that I should replace 'document.createElement()' with 'HtmlService.createElement()' instead? How do I implement HTML Service for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please find [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) the reference for the usage of Apps Script HTML service.

### To summarize the basic steps:

1. If you want to use JS code that is not supported by Apps Script - you need to embed it into the `<script> </script>` part of a HTML file attached to your Apps Script .gs file
2. You can add the HTML file to your script through File->New-> HTML File
3. To call an Apps Script function from the JS part, you need to do it with the  `google.script.run` method
4. To build the HTML file, you need to define your script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) (Publish->Deploy as web app...)
5. You need to embed into your .gs file a `doGet()` function and call `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params)` inside this function

> Alternatively, consider building your script only with methods supported by Apps Script